# How to make DataGridView NotSortable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

DGV has no AllowSort property.
How can I prevent user to sort the items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over gridview columns and set the `SortMode` of each column as this -

```
DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
```

You can also do this `via Designer` :: Go to `Columns` collection > Set `SortMode as NotSortable`

Answer (score 1):

Set the sort value programmatically:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns["Priority"].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
```

or for the whole DataGrid (I am on my mac and dont have my VM MS Machine up so something like):

```
foreach(dataGridView.Columns x in this.dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    x.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b9k0ktw.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressinstall/thread/32c8d256-3fe7-4cf3-84dc-b1322b781c73) describes some possible solutions:

1. Use the `ColumnAdded` [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnadded.aspx):

   ```
   private void MyDGV_ColumnAdded(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
   {
       e.Column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
    }
   ```
2. Override [OnColumnAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.oncolumnadded.aspx):

   ```
   protected override void OnColumnAdded(DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnColumnAdded(e);
       e.Column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
   }
   ```